Custom branch preview URLS on vercel
I deploy my app with vercel and I'd like each git branch to be deployed to <branch>.preview.mycompany. I have seen in the vercel docs that I can specify custom alias domains when deploying, but as far as I can tell, I have to manually create CNAME records for each subdomain, add each one to vercel, and only then can I assign the domain to a deployment. This won't work for me because each preview branch name is different, based on the git branch name. What should I do?
